# JMS call overwriting current jaas subject

Tags: jboss, ejb, jms, jaas

I have an application using JAAS for security having JMS, EJB components running in JBoss AS. The object of javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext is used for verifying permission before calling any method. I have a functionality where I am calling EJB which is secured using role permissions (through ejb deployment descriptor). Before calling the EJB there is a code to put a message in JMS Queue.

The issue is that the subject object contains right user details before the JMS queue code. Once the JMS code is executed the subject changes to guest so the execution to EJB fails as the guest user does not have right role to call EJB. And end up with following exception

```
[org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor] Error in Security Interceptor
java.lang.SecurityException: Denied: caller with subject=Subject:
    Principal: guest
    Principal: Roles(members:john,guest,j2ee)
 and security context post-mapping roles=Roles(john,guest,j2ee,): ejbMethod=someEjbMethod
```

I tried checking option to reassign the initial subject after JMS call so that the EJB context refer to original caller identity but didn't find any.
Any clue or help would be appreciated guys.

Comment: Can you please add the  details of JMS provider ? JBOSS or something else ?

Comment: Hi Monty024, JMS provider is from JBoss AS only, no external provide.